# List of every city in the world, their lattitude, longitude and timezone?

Tags: database, geolocation, geo

I'm sure this question will be closed, but to be frank I'm not sure anywhere else I could ask it.

I need a database/list of every city in the world (not just capitals) with the data to include the name of the city, lattitude, longitude and timezone.

Where might I be able to find such data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. It says it has all cities in the world, lattitude, longitude.
https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database (free, granted it's no longer maintained, good start though)

Comment: You may need to look elsewhere to mix in the timezone. I'm digging a bit deeper.

Comment: Geonames is another option: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone . Also, see this post for how to convert lat/lon into a timezone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates This last link gives many more options to look into.

Comment: ad Geonames: recently I found out that the coordinates are not the center of the city, they are the position where the name of the city can be positioned in a map. They are often outside of the village / city.

Comment: I used Geonames, their data is good and works perfectly with my application

Comment: end of 2019 - looks like maxmind db is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Use this file in your android project's res/values directory
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PKKNGi9IbYshcjvhM9UucpTw86RdxKff

Then get it in your Activity class like

```
          String s[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.popular_cites);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://citiesdatabase.github.io/ if it helps. I found it low cost and has enough sample records to verify authencity.